# silverlight URI not submitting url variables

Tags: php, .net, silverlight, uri

I have a URI like this...

```
the_song.Source = new Uri('index.php?song=blah');
```

Which is being set as the source of a media element.

However, it fails to load, and according to my apache logs (and Firebug giving me a network error), silverlight is only trying to load index.php without the query, which is crucial.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you use another tool, like Fiddler, to see what your silverlight app is actually requesting.

Comment: It is requesting index.php.  That's it.  No query.  And Firebug says the same.

Comment: I just noticed something interesting - if I submit the entire URL like http://127.0.0.1/index.php?song=blah then it works correctly.  But as a relative path it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

Try to make Uri as

```
the_song.Source = new Uri('index.php?song=blah', UriKind.Relative);
```

It might be work.